# I can't get my Fibonacci sequence program in Python to work

Tags: python, fibonacci

I'm trying to write a program to print the first 100 Fibonacci numbers. This is my code:

```
def main():

    print("The first 100 Fibonacci numbers are: ")
    fibonacciList = (0,0,1)
    loop = False

    while not loop:

        listLength = len(fibonacciList)
        newFibonacci = fibonacciList[-1] + fibonacciList[-2]
        fibonacciList = newFibonacci + fibonacciList


        if (listLength > 103):
            loop = true

        print(fibonacciList)

main()
```

When I run it I get the error below referring to the `fibonacciList = newFibonacci + fibonacciList` line:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple'
```

I don't understand what's wrong.

P.S.: The two zeroes in the Fibonacci list are there to prevent a few other errors I got earlier.

Comment: In line `fibonacciList = newFibonacci + fibonacciList`, you are performing `+` over  `newFibonacci` which holds `int` value and `fibonacciList` which is a tuple

Comment: Adding two zeros to the list isn't the right way to fix whatever problem you have. Only one sequence defined by F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2) starts with 2 0s: the infinite list of 0s.

Comment: `fibonacciList = (*fibonacciList, newFibonacci)` might be closer to what you are looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
print("The first 100 Fibonacci numbers are: ")
fibonacciList = (0,0,1)
loop = False

while not loop:

    listLength = len(fibonacciList)
    newFibonacci = fibonacciList[-1] + fibonacciList[-2]
    fibonacciList =  fibonacciList + (newFibonacci,)


    if (listLength > 103):
        loop = True

print(fibonacciList)
```

You can't add an int to a tuple, but you can concatenate two tuples with `+`, so we can tuple-ize the int with `(newFibonacci,)`.

There are more efficient and readable ways to compute this sequence, but this solves your immediate question.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
def main():

    print("The first 100 Fibonacci numbers are: ")
    fibonacciList = [0,0,1]
    loop = False

    while not loop:

        listLength = len(fibonacciList)
        newFibonacci = fibonacciList[-1] + fibonacciList[-2]
        fibonacciList.append(newFibonacci)


        if (listLength > 103):
            loop = True
            print(fibonacciList)

main()
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the other answers you could try the following solution, which is faster, more efficient and better readable:

```
def fib(n):
    fiblist = []
    x, y = 0, 1

    for i in range(n):
        fiblist.append(x)
        x, y = y, x + y

    print('The first {} Fibonacci numbers are: \n{}'.format(n, fiblist))
```

Then for the first 100 Fibonacci numbers call the function as follows:

```
fib(100)
```